# is it proper to refer to living poultry in a location as "native" ones

Tags: word-usage

I know that it is usual to call the people who has lived somewhere as "native" people. is this usual for animals too?
can i call "native poultry" of Asia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better call it *native to somewhere*. You can find references like [*Turkeys are the only breed of **poultry native to the Western Hemisphere.***](http://afghanag.ucdavis.edu/educational-materials/files/poultry/ed-live-afg-purdue-unita-lesson3-external-anatomy.pdf)

However, for humans, you may say "Native Americans"; for animals, it could be "native to ...." The use of 'native ***to***'

Say -

> At the same time, as mentioned above, it has been experimentally proven that black bears ***native to*** the region do not develop such severe disease upon exposure to *N. helminthoeca.*

Alternatively, you can directly call them American black bears.

Answer (score 0):

In a particular country it is possible to have both native or indigenous species living there and introduced species of animals living there.

It is also possible to refer to a species as a native species, you can use the phrase native to as well but it is not necessary.

This is the definition of a [Native Species](http://www.biodiversitya-z.org/content/native-species)  in a UN sponsored page on biodiversity.

A species that has been observed in the form of a naturally occurring and self-sustaining population in historical times.

Bern Convention 1979 1

We refer to those animals that have come to live in that country by themselves as native or indigenous species and those that have been brought to that country by man as an introduced species.

For instance in Britain we have a native Red Squirrel and an introduced species the Grey Squrrel from North America living here.

This leads onto another concept of invasive species, the Red Squirrel is now quite rare in the UK as the larger Grey Squirrel has taken over much of its territory over the past 150 years or so,  since it was introduced. The Grey Squirrel is described as an invasive species in Britain because of this.

To give an example of poultry the Red Grouse is native to the UK, but the Chicken descended from the Jungle Fowl of South a East Asia is not.